# How do I remove a rule that was configured on PanOS via Panorama?

Tags: firewall, palo-alto

I have a problem deleting a rule that was created on Pan-OS via Panorama.

I have Pan-OS firewall (5.0.0) that was managed by Panorama (5.0.0), then I added the Pan-OS to a DG and created some rules.
after a while someone deleted the DG and committed to the Panorama.

Now I have a Pan-OS firewall with a DG rule that I can't remove.

Does someone know how to remove a Panorama rule from Pan-OS?

Comment: I think in the lower left hand view you can delete the rule there.  Should be a delete button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove Panorama rule from Panos. Select the rule and below click on override on firewall and delete the rule. Commit and save changes on that particular box. What is DG?

Answer (score 2):

When you commit in Panorama, select the "Device Group" radio button. There should be a checkbox on the bottom right that says "Force Template Values". I am wondering if you force the template values for the Device Group whether you will delete the rules from the PanOS.

You could also recreate the Device Group and add just this PanOS to the group and commit to see if the policies go away. Then commit again deleting the Device Group.